# What should happen if an answer is deleted during a late answer review?

Tags: support, bug

I was reviewing a late answer and I think the answer was deleted before I completed the review.  I don't think it was an audit.  The comment and edit buttons did nothing even after repeated attempts.  I opened a new tab and found the question, and saw that the answer was not there.  I went back to review and found that "Skip" did work.  It did not tell me I failed the audit, but I am unclear if "Skip" would fail an audit or not.

Am I correct that the answer was deleted?  Or does it just not appear because it is a late answer?  Or did another reviewer flag it before I was done?  Whatever happened, the behavior of doing nothing at all is probably not the optimal result.  Perhaps it should notify the reviewer and auto-skip?

The question was: [Outlook Ribbon Load Inspector.CurrentItem is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was no longer eligible for review, it should have popped up a message informing you that it is no longer available for review.

If it was an audit and you clicked *skip*, you would not pass or fail the audit. Skip is just skipping that review and moving on to the next review.

I think there was just some random bug/something not loading properly that happened when you were reviewing that one. It's actually happened to me recently once or twice. Just do a refresh of the page next time and it should work.